# Change options depending on the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a form with an input URL. I would like to know how do I if the URL is a Youtube video change the input values and the radio label text, if the Vimeo for example change the value and the label text and want to be your one more input radio.

```html
<form method="post" id="form">
<label>URL: <input type="url" size="60px" name="url" ><br>
<div class="examplo">http://www.example.com/304005/name-video</div><br></label>
<b>Tamanho:</b>
<label><input type="radio" name="t" value="488" checked> 488 x 366px</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="t" value="400" > 400 x 300px</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="t" value="240" > 240 x 180px</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="t" value="180" > 180 x 135px</label>
<input type="submit" name="btn" id="buton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What you want to know? Do you want to know what URL user has written in URL text box and want to do some action on it??

Comment: You want to detect is url is either youtube or vimeo then do some js work;

Answer (score 1):

Just use `String.prototype.startsWith` e.g.

```
<label>URL: <input id="foo" type="url" size="60px" name="url" ><br>
```

With

```
const input = document.getElementById('foo');
const value = input.value;
const isYouTube = value.startsWith('http://www.youtube'); // for youtube
```

Comment: I guess OP is dealing with `input` element..Not with the `window.location..`

Comment: Indeed. Fixed answer

Comment: i think its `val` not `valu` for last line :)

Comment: Thanks. I made it all `value` :)

Comment: it will return false because it is not starting with `http://www.youtube.com` text. Your solution won't work if user write "youtube.com";. your solution only work if user write "youtube.com"